# SSRS iif and lookup from three datasets = #error

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where I would like to combine two columns into one. But when I try I get #error where the date should appear - they work fine separately.

How can I do this?

Column 1:

```
=IIf(Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet2") <> "01-01-1754", Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet2"), "")
```

Column 2:

```
=IIf(Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet3") <> "01-01-1754", Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet3"), "")
```

See pic of how the columns looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; please try to format your post by using "block" delimiters for the content of your two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `&` in following:

```
=IIf(Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet2") <> "01-01-1754", Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet2"), "")
&
IIf(Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet3") <> "01-01-1754", Lookup(Fields!Chassis_No.Value, Fields!Chassis_no_.Value, Fields!Date_Performed.Value, "DataSet3"), "")
```